# How to pass to a Generic and Pass from a Generic to another class?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, generics, generic.xaml

When I log into my application, I pass the `cUserEntity` class which holds all the details of the logged in user, including UserID and Username, to the Dashboard form. From here, I can continue to pass the details around from class to class and form to form. For example *(Ignore the generic bit in this example)*:

**Login:**

```
 xamlDashboard Manager = new xamlDashboard(_loggedInUser);
 Generic Gen = new Generic(_loggedInUser);
 Manager.Show();
```

**Dashboard:**

```
cUserEntity _loggedInUser;

  public xamlDashboard(cUserEntity loggedInUser)
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        _loggedInUser = loggedInUser;
    }
```

However, I have a `Generic.Xaml` page which creates a button at the top of every window. Behind the `Generic.xaml` is a Generic class, which holds the `click_event` for the created button. The `click_event` opens a new window to another form.

Now, I need that other form to have the logged in user details, and to do that, I assume I need to pass to the `Generic.Xaml` and then pass from there to the new form via the `click_event`. However, as I've read up and noticed, it doesn't seem to be possible as you can't pass a type to a Generic during runtime.

What I hoped to achieved *(which failed)*:

```
public partial class Generic
{
    cUserEntity _loggedInUser;

    public Generic(cUserEntity loggedInUser)
    {
        _loggedInUser = loggedInUser;
    }

    private void btnHelp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        xamlHelp help = new xamlHelp(_loggedInUser);
        help.Show();
    }
}
```

**Therefore, what is the best and most efficient method to be able to do this, and would appreciate examples, if possible.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be alot simpler to create a singleton object to store your logged in user...

```
public class UserAccount
{
   private static User _currentUser;

   private UserAccount() {}

   public static User CurrentUser
   {
      set
      {
         _currentUser = value;
      }

      get 
      {
         return _currentUser;
      }
   }
}
```

Then after login you would do this...

```
// Set the current User
UserAccount.CurrentUser = user;
```

Then in any class you need the currently logged in user... you could do...

```
var user = UserAccount.CurrentUser;
```

Obviously you would need to implement your own business rules around this but the concept is what I am trying to get across here, a static single instance of the user that can be accessed from anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Never thought about doing that, seems rather stupid the way I was doing it, now that I think about it. Appreciate the help!